# Bootstrap 4 printing uses medium breakpoint

Tags: html, css, printing, bootstrap-4

I recently updated some pages to be more mobile friendly, but the problem is some of our users print off pages and they print using the medium breakpoint (tablet styles) rather than desktop styles. It does this in both portrait and landscape, and it happens in both firefox and chrome

I would like pages to print using the large breakpoint but I can't figure out how.

I even already have the following set:

```
@media print {
    body {
        min-width: 992px !important;
    }
}
```

[Desktop sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuamY.png)

[Print sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIP53.png)

sample jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/jz56frqh/2/show

Answer (score 1):

There are variables to change print sizing in bootstrap variables.scss:

```
$print-page-size:                   a3 !default;
$print-body-min-width:              map-get($grid-breakpoints, "lg") !default;
```

If you want to do it manually in your CSS try this (change min-width to your desired size):

```
@media print {
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 !important;
    min-width: 768px;
  }
  .container {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 750px;
  }
}
```

scss ref: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_variables.scss

Comment: Tried this out but with 992px (as that is the minimum for large breakpoint). I've been testing it out in the print emulator, and the body is doing the minimum width, but styles are still swapping to tablet/mobile and just overflowing outside the window. They are still mobile on the print, but do not overflow

Comment: Did you change .container styles aswell? by the way it would be nice if you add a jsfiddle link of your problem.

Comment: I did yes. I edited my original post to include a sample jsfiddle

Comment: Note that I had to save the iframe source on its own to test the print preview. Jsfiddle styles seem to interfere with it

Comment: have you tried changing page size? its currently set as a3 with this code: @media print { @page{size:a3} }

Comment: I have tried that. I have to set it to be absurdly large for it to work which seems wrong

Comment: set page size to 992px.

Comment: 992px doesn't work. I have to set it 10 1398px or higher to work. The other problem with this is it causes a lot of whitepsace on top and bottom of the content when printing on regular lletter 8.5 x 11 paper

Comment: My goal is to determine a `min-width` that guarantees that nothing is cut off at the right border of the printed page. How can I translate my paper size (a4) to a `min-width`? Is there a fixed dpi print setting?